# PHP calling out query with method

Tags: php, mysql, methods

I am trying to call out method with query, but I can't get it working. I am probably calling it out wrong.

```html
if (!empty($picturename) && !empty($productID)) {
 
 Product::set_main_pic($picturename, $productID);

}
```

```html
public static function set_main_pic($picturename, $productID) {
        global $database;

        if(empty(($picturename) && empty($productID))) {
            return false;
        }
 
             $query = "UPDATE "
            . PX . self::$table_name
            . "SET main_picture = '" . $database->escape_value($picturename) . "' WHERE ID = " . $database->escape_value($productID);

        
            $database->query($query);

        
    }
```

Comment: what do  you mean with "I can't get it working"   .. you have error?

Comment: You have unquoted values in your query: `SET main_picture = " . $database->escape_value($picturename) . "`, you should have quotes around the value.

Comment: I can't see any errors and the database isn't updating.

Comment: use var_dump($query); before $database->query($query); and share the output

Comment: This is what I got. "string(63) "UPDATE katus_products SET main_picture = '123.jpg' WHERE ID = 3" Query is working when inserted manually.

Comment: Also fixed unquoted values what Schlaus mentioned. Still nothing.

Comment: Glad to read that it works now. As a side note: Please read up on placeholder usage in sql-queries and rewrite your code to use them -- interpolating user-supplied data directly into sql is opening a bunch of hard to fix security-issues you avoid by using placeholders. Using db-escape code is a first step, but placeholders operate on a different level -- e.g. the escaping code might be exploitable.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

You must add  a space before SET be sure for self::$table_name

```
$query = "UPDATE "
        . PX . self::$table_name
        . " SET main_picture = " . $database->escape_value($picturename) . " WHERE ID = " . $database->escape_value($productID)
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Fixed that, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: the sql code seem correct .. .. ae you sure you have the right id  ..  ?  .. and that the $database contain what need for accessing database (connection and so on .. )

Comment: $database contains everything what's needed for connection. I have other methods which work, but they are SELECT instead of UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I had one extra unneccesary pair of 
parentheses. Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Fixed:

```
if(empty($picturename) && empty($productID)) {
   return false;
}
```

Before:

```
if(empty(($picturename) && empty($productID))) {
   return false;
}
```